# Аналог window onload для angular?

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular

Есть ли аналог **window.onload** для angular, чтобы событие срабатывало после загрузки изображений и других внешних ресурсов?

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {OnInit} from "@angular/core";


@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['my.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  public ngOnInit(){
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      alert('LOAD!!')
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Что вовсе значит `аналог window.onload для angular`? Как может быть аналог нативного события? Angular не отслеживает загрузку изображений и по дизайну не должен, вопрос в другом - в чем проблема использовать `window.onload`?

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с событиями `window` можно использовать [`HostListener`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)

```
@HostListener('window:load',['$event'])
onPageLoad(event: Event) {
    console.log('loaded',event); 
}
```

В некоторых случаях, возможно заменить его на `ngAfterViewInit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно изучить [ЖЦ копмонентов](https://metanit.com/web/angular2/2.8.php) в `angular` - это весьма необходимо при разработке.

Для вашей задачи вам поможет интерфейс [`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

Comment: AfterViewInit не подходит, т.к. срабатывает раньше чем загрузится весь контент.

Comment: @AlexanderMyravjev контент имеется в виду аяксы и тому подобное ?

Comment: @AlexanderMyravjev посмотрите так же [AfterContentInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit). Асинхронщина в этио не входит

Answer (score 0):

Да, так же нужно учитывать что загрузка картинок, контента, выборка из базы данных асинхронные операции. Здесь так же нужно разобраться с Promise и Observable объектами с RxJS.

Здесь например есть некоторые примеры и объяснения

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCwSVQO_PtY&pbjreload=10